# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializerBase

Tags: swagger-2.0, jackson-databind

```
current version jackson-databind-2.9.10.1.jar
need to upgrade jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar
```

I could not find **ToStringSerializerBase** class in new version of jackson updated jar

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule]:
> Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializerBase

internal dependencies i found

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: You can exclude the jackson-databind dependency from springfox-swagger2 and see if that works? 
`<dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.5</version>
     <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>`

Comment: No that does not solve. Seems application search searching it while running.  org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializerBase
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:132)
 at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWell

Comment: Can you please provide the complete trace?

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar error with Spring vs. Jackson, and solved it, see below.

1. I had a lot of dependencies on Spring stuff, and the below dependencies on Jackson:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

I ran `mvn dependency:tree|grep jackson` and saw clashing versions:

```
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
```

2. So I changed a version of Jackson I directly imported into my `pom.xml` to match Spring's one and all worked smoothly:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy!

Answer (score 8):

**ToStringSerializerBase** is present in version *2.12* of *jackson-databind*

*POM dependecy*

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

*ToStringSerializerBase is present in Jar*

```
(base) rohiagra-mac:faw-qa-api rohiagra$ jar -tvf target/faw-qa-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep "ToStringSerializerBase"
  3347 Sun Nov 29 14:46:22 IST 2020 com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializerBase.class
```

Comment: Fixed it for me!